# Is there any way to increase the timeout connection between Apache web server and tomcat

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, timeout, tomcat9

My Application getting timeout when I am trying to fetch data from sources available on my tomcat server. I can see DB query is the culprit because it is sending data in 100 seconds due to  huge amount of data it is processing. My request getting timeout in 60 seconds which leads to below error

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

I am using mod_proxy to connect to tomcat servers from Apache web server. I tried increasing `connctionTimeout` to 90000 mili-seconds for SSL connector but still request getting timeout in 60 seconds. Is there anything I am missing to change so that I can increase my connection timeout.

I am using tomcat 9. Any leads will be very helpful. As I am stuck here from quite long.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to define proxy timeout value in httpd.conf file. I added below two parameters
Timeout 300
ProxyTimeout 300

For more details you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169453/bad-gateway-502-error-with-apache-mod-proxy-and-tomcat)